# Rails link_to new with parameters not saving parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, link-to

So, I have two objects, Floor, which has_many FloorMonsters, and FloorMonster which belongs_to Floor.

I have a link_to new_floor_monster_path in the show page on Floor, and I intend to pass the Floor id as a parameter. The link_to currently looks like this:

```
= link_to "Add a Monster to this Floor", new_floor_monster_path(floor_id: @floor.id)
```

In the controller for FloorMonster, the new method is this:

```
def new
  @floor_monster = FloorMonster.new(floor_id: params[:floor_id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @floor_monster }
  end
end
```

When I click the link, the URL shows the parameters:

```
http://.../floor_monsters/new?floor_id=4
```

But when I save, the floor_id is nil and the program crashes. What am I missing here? I've tracked down sources that do exactly what I did, but I am getting no succes. [The accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268254/rails-pass-id-parameter-on-a-link-to) and [this blog post](http://www.jacoulter.com/2011/12/09/rails-3-1-passing-a-parameter-to-a-controller-with-link_to/) are doing exactly what I am doing as far as I can tell, but they managed to get it to work.

Comment: What do you have on the FloorMonster new page? From what you've given us you're only using FloorMonster.new in your action, it just creates a new instance, it does not persist it. Do you have a form that submits to a create action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are exposing the new FloorMonster in a form to allow setting other attributes and then saving it.  In order to pass the `floor_id` attribute along to the create action, you will need to add a field to your form for it.  If you don't want it to be seen or to be editable, use a `hidden_field`. In your form, add:

```
= f.hidden_field :floor_id
```